# Refresh IIS site custom settings without restarting it

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis

I have a custom settings file (**Settings.xml**) where I specify all that I need. When changeing that file while running the website the site, of course, restart.

**Settings.xml** is read into an object that have the same structure as the xml and then I work with the `Settings` object

```
private static readonly XDocument Settings = XDocument.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Settings.xml");
```

The site runs in IIS 8.5.

Is it possible to update **Settings.xml** without forceing the website to restart?

Is it the IIS that automatically restart?

Comment: Shot answer - yes it is. Show code where you read your settings into object.

Comment: @teovankot did some updates now, was missing some information

Comment: Look into the [`CacheDependency` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cachedependency(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to implement auto-reload behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read your setting on every file change like this:

```
private static DateTime? _lastSettingRead;
private static XDocument _cahedSettings;
private static XDocument Settings
{
    get
    {
        var settingsPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Settings.xml";
        //Get last change Settings file datetime
        var lastSettingChange = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(settingsPath);
        //If we read first time or file changed since last read
        if (!_lastSettingRead.HasValue || lastSettingChange > _lastSettingRead)
        {
            _lastSettingRead = lastSettingChange; //change read date
            _cahedSettings = XDocument.Load(settingsPath); //load settings to field
        }
        return _cahedSettings; //return cached settings from field
    }
}
```

Comment: Will that prevent IIS to restart the website? The whole point is that I dont want to restart the website (or recycle appPool, not sure what happens) when changeing the configuration file

Comment: @MrProgram yes it will. The whole point is when you will try to get settings from `Settings` property it will check has been file changed since last read. If so - this code will read settings again without IIS reset.